# xsl counter with and condition

Tags: xslt

i've a condition where the section element should be having both a num attribute and level can be any apart from level 2. like below.

```
<section level="sect2" num="1.">
    <title>Flowchart&#x2014;HKIAC Mediation</title>
</section>  

 <section level="sect3">
    <title>Flowchart&#x2014;HKIAC Mediation</title>
</section>

<section level="sect2">
    <title>Flowchart&#x2014;HKIAC Mediation</title>
</section>
```

and when i use the below xslt it is counting only the first xml with number attribute and leaving second and third. but i want to count both first and third leaving second.

i've used the below statement

```
<xsl:number count='section[@num]'/>
```

but i want something similar to below

```
<xsl:number count='section[@num] and section[@level!='sect2']'/>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<xsl:number count="section[@num and @level != 'sect2']"/>
```

For your issue in the comment try this which means num attribute not present -

```
<xsl:number count="section[not(@num) and @level = 'sect2']"/>
```

You mean you do not care if the level=sect2 then just remove that like this -

```
<xsl:number count="section[not(@num)]"/>
```

This will give you count where num attribute is not present and value of level is not sect2.

```
<xsl:number count="section[not(@num) and @level != 'sect2']"/>
```

Comment: Hi @Bhushan, thanks for the reply, this is working fine, but here i've got another problem, it should count sec2 only if the num attribute is not null. please let me know how do i do it. Thanks

Comment: The updated is working fine and is counting only level sect2 with not num as attribute, but is not not counting if the level attribute is not sect2

Comment: Hi Bhushan, also it should check if the level is something apart from 2

Comment: Dude can you provide what you need in one go? Also please try to understand the concept and learn. I have updated my answer. Also I guess I deserve a vote up at least.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding its more:

```
<xsl:number count="section[@num or @level != 'sect2']"/>
```

Because: 
 but i want to count both first and third leaving second.
EDIT: Seems it should be fist and second 
What seems to be all section with "@level != 'sect2'" and all section with "@num".

Comment: but here irt will count the second one also as @level is set to sect2, i want if level is sect2 it should have a number attribute then it should be count and any level apart from level with sec2 should be count

Comment: Hm so you like to count first and second entry in your example. Which would be `[@num or @level != 'sect2']`