# Count inside an if condition

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a xml document, which includes several blocks of test definitions. With an xsl transformation, I want to merge some of these test definition blocks together, when they have the same name. 
After they have been merged, I want to assign a number (Order) to each merged test definition.

**Example input:**
(Order being 0 everywhere is deliberate, since I don't know at this point, how many tests will still be there after the merging)

```
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result1"/>
        <Result Name="Result2"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result5"/>
        <Result Name="Result6"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Order>0</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result3"/>
        <Result Name="Result4"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
```

**Wanted Output:** 
(Now every merged test has an Order number assigned, starting with 1 and counting up without gaps)

```
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result1"/>
        <Result Name="Result2"/>
        <Result Name="Result3"/>
        <Result Name="Result4"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
    <Order>2</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result5"/>
        <Result Name="Result6"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
```

**Current Output:** 
(the Order tag of Test2 is the important point)

```
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test1</Name>
    <Order>1</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result1"/>
        <Result Name="Result2"/>
        <Result Name="Result3"/>
        <Result Name="Result4"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
<TestDef>
    <Name>Test2</Name>
    <Order>3</Order>
    <Results>
        <Result Name="Result5"/>
        <Result Name="Result6"/>
    </Results>
</TestDef>
```

**My current xslt:**

```
<xsl:key name="unique-tests" match="TestDef" use="Name" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Merge all tests with the same name together and add all results to
the one new test
This grouping was done, using the Muenchian Method: 
http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html -->    
<xsl:template match="TestDef">
    <xsl:if test="generate-id()= generate-id(key('unique-tests', Name))">
        <Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
        </Name>
        <Order>
            <xsl:number />
        </Order>
        <Results>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('unique-tests', Name)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Results/node()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Results>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**The problem:**

The grouping works just fine, but the order number just won't work the way I want it to. When I use `<xsl:number/>` like in my shown xslt, then he will count **every** test from the input, but only output some of the numbers. The output for my example would maybe be something like Test1 with order = 1 and Test2 with order = 3.

When I add an additional output of `<xsl:number/>` before the if condition, he will output every number in order, even though the test definition itself won't be there in the output.

Now I have seen other questions like this one: [xsl counter with and condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034873/xsl-counter-with-and-condition)
There they count with an condition, but since my own condition cannot be represented as an XPath, I can't use it for the `count` attribute of `<xsl:number/>`

So, I want to have the Order tag count from 1 to whatever number of TestDefs I have in the **Output**, without any gaps. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, it would be best to to apply templates selectively - i.e only to those `TestDef` elements that are first in their group - then use the `position()` function to number them.

To demonstrate, we must first have a valid XML input with a single root element, e.g.:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <TestDef>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Order>0</Order>
        <Results>
            <Result Name="Result1"/>
            <Result Name="Result2"/>
        </Results>
    </TestDef>
    <TestDef>
        <Name>Test2</Name>
        <Order>0</Order>
        <Results>
            <Result Name="Result5"/>
            <Result Name="Result6"/>
        </Results>
    </TestDef>
    <TestDef>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <Order>0</Order>
        <Results>
            <Result Name="Result3"/>
            <Result Name="Result4"/>
        </Results>
    </TestDef>
</root>
```

Then you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="unique-tests" match="TestDef" use="Name" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="TestDef[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique-tests', Name)[1])]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TestDef">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select="Name" /></Name>
        <Order><xsl:value-of select="position()" /></Order>
        <Results>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('unique-tests', Name)">
                <xsl:copy-of select="Results/node()"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Results>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Alternatively, you could duplicate your condition to the `xsl:number` too, by using:

```
<xsl:number count="TestDef[generate-id() = generate-id(key('unique-tests', Name)[1])]"/>
```

Comment: Hm, I didn't know you could put the condition in a way like that into the count attribute. I'll try it when I'm back at work tomorrow and get back to you!

Comment: I went with your second option, since with the first one, the grouping did not work at all. But with the condition in the count parameter, everything is working as expected. Thank you very much :)

Comment: "*with the first one, the grouping did not work at all.*" Does this work for you: http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtS ? -- The flaw in the second option is that it violates the DRY principle.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the xslt in your link is exactly the same as the one in your answer? It's got the same problem, but I think it's mostly down to the fact, that I only posted a simplified version of my xml and I did something wrong, with adapting your xslt to it. Anyway, with this site I think I'm able to debug it myself (btw, this site is _awesome_!) So thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it's the same XSLT; I wanted to show you that it does work. We can only see with what you show us.